# Difference between [] and [[]] in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone pleas tell what's difference between (if a is some numppy object, lets say:array) a[1] and a[[1]]. If I understand correctly I can edit 1 element of a with a[[1]], but not with a[1]...any other difference? Is it also something like  that with [] I just view some element(s) and with [[]] I make copy?
If it's to any importance I'm using python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `a[1]` you are getting the element with index `1` (the second one) from `a`. `a[[1]]`, on the other hand, is not a special syntax, it just means "get the elements of `a` indicated by the indices in the list `[1]`". You can also say `a[[1, 2]]`, or use another array as index. The practical difference is that `a[1]` will be a single scalar element and `a[[1]]` will be an array with size 1 (assuming `a` had one dimension).

With respect to assignment, you will find that both `a[1] = 2` and `a[[1]] = 2` work equally well. This is because of NumPy's [broadcasting semantics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which allow you to match objects of different dimensions seamlessly. However, the actual dimensions of `a[1]` and `a[[1]]` are different, and it does matter depending on the context.

You can read more about indexing in NumPy [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).